# Postgres: integer out of range. Why this error occur?

Tags: sql, postgresql, type-conversion

I have two queries. I expect both insert same value: `429496729600`, but one of them fail because of error:

```
db=> update order_detail set amount = 400*1024*1024*1024 where id = 11;
ERROR:  integer out of range
db=> update order_detail set amount = 429496729600 where id = 11;
UPDATE 1
```

Why the error occur for first query?

**UPD**
Forget to specify that type of `amount` is `bigint` and the

```
400*1024*1024*1024 == 429496729600
```

Comment: Your number is bigger than integer. The first insert have a computation before inserting. As you multiply integer postgres expect an Integer as result. It is not so it fail.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To force the multiplication to output a bigint instead of an int, you can cast 1 to a bigint and multiply

```
select cast(1 as bigint)*400*1024*1024*1024;
   ?column?
--------------
 429496729600
```

Comment: Can you explain why your solution works (thank you so much by the way :-D) but this one does not: `CAST((400*1024*1024*1024) AS bigint)`?

Comment: @jeffdill2 because in your example the multiplication is done before casting, and since each term in the multiplication is an int, the outcome is also an int and the result is too big to fit in an int.

Comment: AH, of course! Thanks. 

Answer (score 5):

`int`  maximum value of 2<sup>31</sup>-1, the first Update value greater than it so caulse the erorr.

> `INT` -2147483648 to +2147483647

You can try to let `amount` column to `BIGINT` Type

> `BIGINT`-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807

```
ALTER TABLE order_detail ALTER COLUMN amount TYPE BIGINT;
```

[Data Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html)

---

**EDIT**

we can use `pg_typeof` to check it out.

**Query #1**

*postgresql* will let `429496729600` be `BIGINT` because of the value greater than int range.

```
SELECT pg_typeof(429496729600 );

| pg_typeof |
| --------- |
| bigint    |
```

---

**Query #2**

When you do multiplication in number that will translate to `int`.

```
SELECT pg_typeof( 1*15*1  );

| pg_typeof |
| --------- |
| integer   |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8hNAN8Q3Vkn99EBvU78Kby/2)

**Query**

You can use `400*1024*1024*1024:: BIGINT` let `int` convert to `bigint`.

```
SELECT 400*1024*1024*1024 :: BIGINT;

| ?column?     |
| ------------ |
| 429496729600 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8hNAN8Q3Vkn99EBvU78Kby/3)

Comment: ok, thanks. You show me the problem. but another answer show how to resolve it.